# Does WunderBar support Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, acceptance-testing, microprofile, wunderbar

I have both, a Spring Boot client and server application. Can I test these with [WunderBar](https://github.com/t1/wunderbar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, WunderBar is in its current form tied to the MicroProfile/JEE technology stack. The `bar` files, however, could be produced or used on other tech stacks by other libraries.

OTOH, there's an [issue#16](https://github.com/t1/wunderbar/issues/16) that would allow to produce and consume [pact files](https://pact.io/), which would allow mixing the technology stacks.